# Can I add MySQL onto my EC2 instance that already has Node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to make a website using Node.js on AWS EC2 and I need help deciding how I should add on MySQL. Note this is my first time doing this.

My first question is can I download and use mysql and put it on the same EC2 instance that has Node.js?

I know that you can create an EC2 or a RDS instance to make a MySQL database.

Next I'm just wondering what is the best: to put it on the same instance or to have Node.js and MySQL have their own instance and connect them? if anybody can help me have a better understanding that would be awesome.

I have tried making a local project on my desktop with Node.js and mysql, just never done it on AWS.

Comment: Yes. Whats best depends on your ec2 instance size whether you want to manage mysql yourself etc.. etc.. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First thing, ec2 instance is a noramlly a PC/System just like our PC, ec2 can have different OS like windows,linux,ubuntu,etc.. just like your local PC, difference is that you are have you access the server using terminal. so you can login using your ssh credentials as root and you can install Nodejs, MYSQL, as Nodejs is a language used for your backend and MYSQL is a database, so can install the MYSQL and run it and connect it with you backend

Answer (score 0):

So, answer to your first question, “can I download and use MySQL and put it on the same EC2 instance that has Node.js?” is YES. You can download and use MySQL on the same instance on which you have Node.js. As both are different like one is database whereas other is an application.

Although the performance of the application will depend upon the size of your EC2 instance. It will be a good option if you have a larger instance type with high configurations.

But the best solution is to use Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) which results in your application for the following benefits :

1. Amazon RDS lets you create your database in minimal time using
   AWS Management Console, Command Line Interface, or API calls.
2. It makes maintenance very easy as it takes automated backups as well
   as a point in time snapshots for recovery which is way better than the traditional database services where most of the time is spent in database maintenance and setup.
3. Amazon RDS will be highly available and also provides failover
   support with Multi-AZ deployments.

**Limitation of RDS** is that Amazon takes care of Infrastructure, Backups and Updates whereas for **MySQL installed on your EC2** instance you will have all the advantages of the AWS Cloud platform and services, as well as the ability to use MySQL plugins and other MySQL features that are unavailable on Amazon RDS.
Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I will try using RDS.